# API stops working until a request is made on GoDaddy server

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, iis

I am having issues about running an API on Godaddy server. The API basically sends requests to a website constantly in a certain period time as soon as it starts to operate. Therefore it has timer that is created in Application_Start for controlling this action. For some reason, my API stops working after some time if no one makes a request. However I need my API to work all the time since I need a list that has live data which is collected from another website. Below you can read the steps I take and problem that I encounter in details:

1. I created my Web API on Visual Studio 2013 written in C#.
2. I bought the server from Godaddy having Windows Deluxe hosting.
3. I uploaded my files to httpdocs folder of my server using ftp.
4. When I call my API by typing "mysite.com/myWebAPI/myList" it starts to work and initially it returns an empty list (which is normal i think)
5. Then I make same request in 2 seconds (allow my API to collect data) and the list that I desire is returned with live data inside collected from another website.
6. After this point, my API should not stop. It has to send request every X seconds to a website and update the information in the list.
7. However, after 5 or 10 minutes, if no one sends a request then my API stops therefore it stops collecting information from another website and list is not updated.
8. Then, if another request is made, it becomes active again and starts to work but now my list is empty once again. This means that the list is created all over again. This can only happen if Application_Start is called once more.

Note that when I am running this Web API on my localhost server, it works perfectly. It does not stop and gathers the information correctly by sending requests to the website in every X seconds. Even though I don't make any request for 30 minutes, it returns me the list I want after I send request when 30 minutes have passed.

So the question is, **Is there a way to fix this problem and make my API work all the time without stopping on a GoDaddy server having Windows Deluxe Hosting?**

I may have to do something in IIS application pool thing but I am not sure what to do.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: IIS has an idle timeout, when it receives no requests, it puts the site to sleep to conserve server resources.  Do you have access to the idle time timeout setting for the API's app pool?  If so, you can set it to a higher limit. If you can't change it (or even if you can) might want to look at Quartz scheduler or some other method of running a scheduled task.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I contacted with Godaddy and apparently you cannot adjust anything about app pool. I am now trying to schedule task but it gives 500 internal server error stating "There is a problem with the resource you are looking for, and it cannot be displayed." On Godaddy, when you upload things to httpdocs everything works fine but when you open a subfolder, you always have a problem. I will let people know if I fix this so that others won't deal with such thing in future.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure specifically about GoDaddy, but on Azure Web App Service this is also common and it is resolved by enabling the 'always on' feature which presumably automates the job of pinging the API every x minutes. If GoDaddy has a similar feature, enabling it may solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

1. Create a scheduled task to ping your API before the IIS idle
   timeout.
   http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12117/Simulate-a-Windows-Service-using-ASP-NET-to-run-sc

   http://www.quartz-scheduler.net/
2. You can also setup Pingdom to ping your API.